# C# service performance issue with Json.NET and GC Wait

Tags: c#, multithreading, garbage-collection, json.net, dottrace

I have a windows service that do some business work. I profile it with dotTrace to find performance issue and have a picture like this:
[GC Wait 88%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbUQj.png)

It seems strange that GC Wait take 88% time, so I get closed look at some small interval and get:
[Thread stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9ij0.png)

I found that during not bloking period, threads allocate object 
through JSON.Net deserilization and also this code blocked by GC:

```
    using (var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, combinedTokenSource.Token))
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        if (response.Content == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No HTTP response received.");

        using (var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            using (var textReader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(responseStream)))
            {
                var results = new JsonSerializer().Deserialize<ElasticResponse>(textReader);
                return results;
            }
        }
    }
```

Did anyone have a similar problem? Or am I missing something?

Comment: So do you have actual perfomance problem or just decided to measure?

Comment: Yes, I have low performance for this cases.

Comment: Can you select ".NET Memory Allocations" then show us content of the "Call Stack" panel? It's even better if you can upload the trace file somewhere

Comment: Also, it looks like the GC is running on a single thread. Enabling concurrent GC would give you some relief. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcconcurrent-element

Comment: Upload trace to https://yadi.sk/d/64xfxnrY3Qz7zg

Answer (score 3):

Finally i found that my app dosen't use "background server garbage collection" (microsoft says it is default in .net 4.5 - [gc description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#background_server_garbage_collection)). So I add to config:

```
   <runtime>  
      <gcServer enabled="true"/>  
   </runtime>
```

and it reduce GC Wait time to 8.5%, as a result I get 5x performance progress.

Comment: Wow, this solved my performance issue! I had a client and a server application. The server was a producer and the client a consumer. The average delay between producing and consuming an item was 150ms, now after applying this on the server app the average delay is 7ms! I had been profiling and refactoring the app for 2 weeks, low delay was a critical goal to achieve. I never though that it was the GC that was blocking my threads, I was pretty sure it was some unefficient locking

Answer (score 0):

The default is workstation GC

[Workstation GC is used by default in all managed apps and is best suited for UI applications](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2017/01/05/understanding-different-gc-modes-with-concurrency-visualizer/)